# Python telnetlib seems not imported and returns "no attribute" errors

Tags: python, telnet

I am struggling for 4 hours now on a stupid problem I have with Python.

My version of Python is 2.7.10, the telnet module is included in it as I did watch the whole module list, and I tried some different files in order to check if it's a global error. It is.

Here is one of my tries, in a file called `run.py` :

```
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib

HOST = "localhost"
user = raw_input("Enter your remote account: ")
password = getpass.getpass()

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.read_until("login: ")
tn.write(user + "\n")
if password:
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(password + "\n")

tn.write("ls\n")
tn.write("exit\n")

print tn.read_all()
```

I then run it in my terminal, and get those errors :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 3, in <module>
    import telnetlib
  File "/Users/Thao/Desktop/telnetlib.py", line 9, in <module>
    >>> tn = Telnet('www.python.org', 79)   # connect to finger port
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Telnet'
```

I don't find any solution to this, as the telnetlib is already installed natively with Python...

What is the issue with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the error message,

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "run.py", line 3, in 
>       import telnetlib
>     File **"/Users/Thao/Desktop/telnetlib.py"**, line 9, in 
>        tn = Telnet('www.python.org', 79)   # connect to finger port
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Telnet'

you have a file named `telnetlib.py` on your Desktop and python is importing that instead of the *real* `telnetlib` module. You will want to either remove the offending file or rename it so as to not interfere with the built-in.

Comment: Indeed, there was a `telnetlib.pyc` on the desktop and now I have a bunch of other errors I have to figure out WHY ! But thanks !

Comment: I wanted but there is "waiting" time, so I can only valid your answer after 5 minutes or so... :-)

Comment: @ThaoD5 Oh! Interesting. I never realized that! I learned something new today too